# How to list files in directory using bash?

Tags: bash

How to copy only the regular files in a directory (ignoring sub-directories and links) to the same destination? (bash on Linux)
**A very large number of files**

Comment: How is this off topic? I really hate this part of stackoverflow.

Comment: I suspect the rational is that this should go to something like Super User, which I kind of understand, but also this is a legit bash programming question.

Comment: can you rephrase the headline...this is how to copy, not how to list

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
for file in /source/directory/*
do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        #copy stuff ....
    fi
done
```

Comment: It also won't respect files with whitespace in the name.

Comment: @holygeek: No, globbing (pathname expansion) is _not_ subject to the `ARG_MAX` max. command-line length limitation, because there is no external utility involved. That said, any loop with a large number of iterations in Bash will be _slow_.

Comment: @glennjackman: Filenames with whitespace _are_ handled correctly, due to use of `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]`; `[[ ... ]]` doesn't require double-quoting variable references (in most cases).

Answer (score 29):

To list regular files in `/my/sourcedir/`, not looking recursively in subdirs:

```
find /my/sourcedir/ -type f -maxdepth 1
```

To copy these files to `/my/destination/`:

```
find /my/sourcedir/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} /my/destination/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks :). I'd to add * to get list of all files inside sourcedir. `find /data/* -maxdepth 2 -type f`

Answer (score 9):

To expand on [poplitea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265272/how-to-list-files-in-directory-using-bash/7265287#7265287), you don't have to exec cp for each file: use `xargs` to copy multiple files at a time:

```
find /my/sourcedir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /my/destination
```

or

```
find /my/sourcedir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -t /my/destination '{}' +
```

Comment: `-exec ... +` is the most efficient solution; one thing worth mentioning: `cp -t` is a _GNU_ extension.