# How to list only files and not directories of a directory Bash?

Tags: bash, file-listing

How can I list all the files of one folder but not their folders or subfiles. In other words: How can I list only the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2437452), [How to list files in directory using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7265272), [Shell script print out file names when given a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45705896), [List files in current directory with full path using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22992790), [What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1690809), [Show files in current directory using Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28738331), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: None of the proposed duplicates seem to implement the requirement to omit directories.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Using the `-maxdepth 1` option ensures that you only look in the current directory (or, if you replace the `.` with some path, that directory). If you want a full recursive listing of all files in that and subdirectories, just remove that option.

Comment: After my comment to mklement0's answer, I realized that "find ./*.png -maxdepth 1 -type f > pngs.txt" would probably accomplish the same. It does. Without installing a script.

Comment: `find` on mac, does not have neither `-type`, nor `-maxdepth` options.

Comment: @Tim: `-type` and `-maxdepth` aren't _options_ in the normal sense; BSD `find` (as used on OS X) calls them _primaries_, and they must come _after_ the filename operand(s) (`.`, in this case; note that, unlike on Linux, the BSD version needs at least one explicit filename operand); the command in this answer definitely works on a Mac.

Comment: @AlexHall: That's a clever solution (though I suggest `find *.png -maxdepth 0 -type f` to avoid the `./` prefix in the output filenames; also note the `-maxdepth` of `0`, not `1`), as 
long as all you need is the file _names_ in _alphabetical order_. If you want what `ls` can otherwise do for you (different output format/ordering, inline control over whether hidden items are included or not), supplemented with [multi-]type filtering, the script from my answer can help.

Comment: To contrast `find * -maxdepth 0 -type f` (an alternative derived from @AlexHall's comment) with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` from the answer:
`find . ...` invariably includes hidden items, invariably prefixes output filenames with `./`, and, with GNU `find` (Linux), typically outputs an unsorted list.
`find * ...`, due to letting the _shell_ perform globbing up front, by default excludes hidden items (can be changed with `shopt -s dotglob`), outputs mere filenames (no prefix), sorted alphabetically.
Neither approach includes _symlinks to_ files; use option `-L` to do so.

Comment: @Tim yes, basically because it is not POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html `ls -p | grep -v` is though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574794/how-to-list-only-files-in-bash/46135507#46135507

Answer (score 40):

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

ls -p lets you show / after the folder name, which acts as a tag for you to remove.

Comment: It's nice to see an example using `ls` in addition to `find`, since the latter returns relative paths and the former only filenames. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: hi! this doesn't work for me. did you mean `ls -p | grep -v ./`

Answer (score 9):

- [carlpett's `find`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574806/45375) (`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`) works in principle, but is **not quite the same as using `ls`: you get a potentially *unsorted* list of filenames all *prefixed with `./`*, and you lose the ability to apply `ls`'s many *options***;
  also `find` ***invariably* finds *hidden* items too**, whereas `ls`' behavior depends on the presence or absence of the `-a` or `-A` options.

  - An **improvement**, suggested by [Alex Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397555/alex-hall) in a comment on the question is to **combine *shell globbing* with `find`**:

    ```
     find * -maxdepth 0 -type f  # find -L * ... includes symlinks to files
    ```

    - However, while this **addresses the prefix problem and gives you alphabetically sorted output**, you still have neither (inline) control over inclusion of hidden items nor access to `ls`'s many other sorting / output-format options.
- [Hans Roggeman's **`ls` + `grep` answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259116/45375) is pragmatic, but **locks you into using long (`-l`) output format**.

---

To address these limitations I wrote the [**`fls`** (**f**iltering **ls**) utility](https://github.com/mklement0/fls),

- **a utility that provides the *output flexibility of `ls`* while also providing *type-filtering capability***,
- simply by placing **type-filtering characters** such as **`f` for files, `d` for directories, and `l` for symlinks** before a list of `ls` arguments (run `fls --help` or `fls --man` to learn more).

**Examples:**

```
fls f        # list all files in current dir.
fls d -tA ~  #  list dirs. in home dir., including hidden ones, most recent first
fls f^l /usr/local/bin/c* # List matches that are files, but not (^) symlinks (l)
```

---

### Installation

**Supported platforms**

- When installing from the **npm registry**: **Linux** and **macOS**
- When installing **manually**: any **Unix-like** platform with **Bash**

#### From the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fls)

<sup>Note: Even if you don't use Node.js, its package manager, `npm`, works across platforms and is easy to install; try

[`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install)</sup>

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed, install as follows:

```
[sudo] npm install fls -g
```

**Note**:

- Whether you need `sudo` depends on how you installed Node.js / io.js and whether you've [changed permissions later](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions); if you get an `EACCES` error, try again with `sudo`.
- The `-g` ensures [*global* installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and is needed to put `fls` in your system's `$PATH`.

#### Manual installation

- Download [this `bash` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/fls/stable/bin/fls) as `fls`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x fls`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (macOS) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

Comment: Brilliant. Even if it involves creating another script. I copied and pasted from the plain text source you link to, into a text file, and ran it in Cygwin with this command:

fls.sh f *.png > pngs.txt

And bingo: a list of .png files without paths.

But really, ls doesn't have an option comparable to DOS' "dir /b" switch? I looked through the contents of ls' --help output, and nothing of the sort is there, at least.

Comment: @AlexHall: Thanks; tl;dr: try `-1` (the number one); `ls` actually defaults to "bare" output, i.e., filenames only, but when outputting to a terminal uses a column-based layout (multiple filenames per line). To get one filename per output line (which is what `dir /b` does, if memory serves), use the `-1` option, which is actually implicitly on when stdout is _not_ connected to a terminal, such as when sending to a pipe or output file.

Answer (score 7):

### Listing content of some directory, without subdirectories

I like using `ls` options, for sample:

> - `-l`                         use a long listing format
> - `-t`                         sort by modification time, newest first
> - `-r`                         reverse order while sorting
> - `-F`, `--classify`             append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
> - `-h`, `--human-readable`       with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc...

Sometime `--color` and all others. (See `ls --help`)

#### Listing everything but folders

This will show files, symlinks, devices, pipe, sockets etc.

so

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 ! -type d
```

could be sorted by date easily:

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -exec ls -hltrF {} +
```

#### Listing *files* only:

or

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

sorted by size:

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -lSF --color {} +
```

#### Prevent listing of *hidden entries*:

To not show hidden entries, where name begin by a dot, you could add `! -name '.*'`:

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name '.*' -exec ls -hltrF {} +
```

Then

You could replace `/some/path` by `.` to list for *current directory* or `..` for *parent directory*.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ls` with `grep` or `egrep` and put it in your profile as an alias:

```
ls -l | egrep -v '^d'
ls -l | grep -v '^d'
```

Comment: I wouldn't put this in a script for the reason given above, but another quick-and-dirty solution: ls -F | grep -v '/$'

Comment: @mooie, what does the '/$' mean or why does it remove the directories from the output of ls?

Comment: @Classified "ls -F" displays a slash ("/") immediately after each pathname that is a directory.  "grep" uses the dollar sign ("$") to indicate an end of a line.  So "grep '/$'" would match all lines outputted by "ls -F" that end in a slash, i.e. directories.  "grep -v" prints all non-matching lines, i.e. everything but directories, which will be file names (and symbolic links).

Answer (score 2):

find files:       ls -l /home | grep "^-" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9

find directories: ls -l /home | grep "^d" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9

find links:       ls -l /home | grep "^l" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9

tr -s ' ' turns the output into a space-delimited file
the cut command says the delimiter is a space, and return the 9th field (always the filename/directory name/linkname).

I use this all the time!

Comment: Wow! What if filenames do contain spaces?

Comment: use "9-" to get everything from the 9th field on. Links also are affected by this since they'll be after the 9th field.

Answer (score 1):

### You are welcome!

```
ls -l | grep '^-'
```

### Looking just for the name, pipe to `cut` or `awk`.

```
ls -l | grep '^-' | awk '{print $9}'

ls -l | grep '^-' | cut -d " " -f 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs ls -1t | less; }
```

added `xargs` to make it works, and used `-1` instead of `-l` to show only filenames without additional `ls` info

Comment: This has some merit, in that it enforces sorting by time, though there are arguably less clumsy ways to do that with `find -printf0 '...' | sort -z`

Answer (score 0):

You can one of these:

```
echo *.* | cut -d ' ' -f 1- --output-delimiter=$'\n'
echo *.* | tr ' ' '\n'
echo *.* | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'
ls -Ap | sort | grep -v /
```

Answer (score 0):

This method does not use external commands.

```
bash$ res=$( IFS=$'\n'; AA=(`compgen -d`); IFS='|'; eval compgen -f -X '@("${AA[*]}")' )

bash$ echo "$res"
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

to list only file names (and directories at final point) without folders and anything else (properties, sizes etc)
I used:

```
  ls -aRp
```

- a=all entries (not ignore entries start with ".")
- R=recursive (in
  all subfolders)
- p=append "/" indicator to directories (if you like to
  clean them later) eg. /temp/list/a1/ will be listed as /a1 only

if you like to compare file existence in two different places then apply this too but it sort all files and directories independently of folder structure.

```
  ls -aRp |  sort --dictionary-order
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ls -l | grep -v '^d'  | awk '{print $9}'
```

Answer (score -2):

Just adding on to carlpett's answer.
For a much useful view of the files, you could pipe the output to ls.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f|ls -lt|less
```

Shows the most recently modified files in a list format, quite useful when you have downloaded a lot of files, and want to see a non-cluttered version of the recent ones.

Comment: This probably doesn't behave as you expect! `ls` doesn't read standard input, so it's useless to pipe anything to `ls`. Did you miss `xargs`?

Comment: To put it differently: the `find` command in this answer is completely _ignored_; the overall command is the same as `ls -lt | less`, which performs _no_ type filtering.

Comment: Though with GNU `find` you could do `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls`. It also seems to work on Mac OS, though I believe `-maxdepth` and `-ls` are not properly portable options.

Answer (score -2):

"find '-maxdepth' " does not work with my old version of bash, therefore I use:

for f in $(ls) ; do if [ -f $f ] ; then echo $f ; fi ; done

Comment: The use of `for f in $(ls)` is doubly wrong. You could fix that with `for f in *`but then it would break because you are not quoting the argument to `echo` properly.