# How can I add all the files and none of the directories during initial git add?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a directory with a bunch of files and other directories in git.

If I do

```
git init .
git add .
```

I will be adding everything including the directories to my git repository.
However, if I only want the files in the current directory to be added (no recursive traversal of directories), is there a non-manual way to do it?

The manual way would be to pick out the files using another tool and running git-add on these files.

Comment: What's wrong with using another tool?  Isn't that what the command line is all about?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with another tool, but it seems to be such a basic functionality that I think git ought to have it, but I havne't figured out how.

Comment: I guess I don't see why the git developers would add something that other tools already do more easily and better; that's just effort & debugging, right?  Sort of against the UNIX philosophy, I'd say.

Comment: Am I missing a requirement here or could you just browse to that directory and do git add \*.\*  which would just grab the files

Comment: I'm trying to get files in the top-level directory and ignore subdirectories.

Comment: I might be missing something but that is what it does on my system.  It just grabs the files of the current directory you are in and ignores everything else but might be that I am using the windows version of git and have no way to test it on linux until later

Comment: @Midpipps that would leave out all files which contain no dot (extensionless files) and all files starting with a dot (e.g. `.gitignore`)

Comment: Ah never thought about that sorry

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
git add --interactive
```

which will allow you to pick files one by one.  Could be onerous; but it would allow you to skip directories.  And you've got this:

```
find . -depth 1 -and ! -type d -exec git add {} \;
```

Here is an example:

```
ebg@tsuki(26)$ find . -depth  1 -and ! -type d -print
./a
./b
ebg@tsuki(27)$ find . -depth  1 -and ! -type d -exec git add {} \;
ebg@tsuki(28)$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   a
#   new file:   b
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   c/
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Git does not have a functionality like that built in.
You can easily do it with a shell loop though. Assuming you're using bash, this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `ls -A`; do
    if [ -f $f ]; then
        git add $f
    fi
done
```

which will add all files from the current directory.

Note that like all bash scripts, you can write this on one line if you only need it once:
`for f in $(ls -A); do if [ -f $f ]; then git add $f; fi; done`

This is just a proof of concept script and could certainly be improved; e.g. it could first construct a list and then call `git add` once on that list.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs git add --
```

perhaps?

The first part lists all files in the current directory (but not in subdirectories, due to `-maxdepth`), `xargs` appends this list as arguments to `git add`.

You can also try the more robust

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec git add -- \{\} \+
```

if your version of `find` supports it. (Or replace `\+` by `\;`, but this will run slower.)

See also: [Bash: How to list only files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574794/946850)

Comment: That will find all files recursively, including files in the subdirectories which I am trying to exclude.

Comment: @merlin2011: That's what `-maxdepth` is supposed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your files and directories are named, there's always the trusty:

```
git add *.*
```

Comment: you should mentioned that that would leave out all files which contain no dot (extensionless files) and all files starting with a dot (e.g. `.gitignore`)