# List files in current directory with full path using Bash

Tags: bash, list, file, shell, path

**Situation**

I have the following Structure:

```
+ Folder 1
--20140410.txt
--20140409.txt
--20140408.txt
--20140407.txt
--20140406.txt
--20140405.txt
--20140404.txt

+ Folder 2
--20140410.txt
--20140409.txt
--20140408.txt
--20140407.txt
--20140406.txt
--20140405.txt
--20140404.txt
```

I need the "newest" (depending on the file name) 5 Files from that directory, including  Path.
Currently i'm using the following code to do so:

```
for i in `find /mydirectory/ -type d` ; do cd $i && ls *.* | sort -n -r | head -5 >> /mydirectory/myfile.txt ; done
```

So for every directory I find, I list the files, inverse-sort them by name and cut after line 5.

Here's the result:

```
20140410.txt
20140409.txt
20140408.txt
20140407.txt
20140406.txt
20140410.txt
20140409.txt
20140408.txt
20140407.txt
20140406.txt
```

How do i write the current working directory "before" the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use `find` again:

```
for i in $(find /mydirectory/ -type d); do cd $i && find $PWD -type f -name "*.*" | sort -nr | head -5 >> /mydirectory/myfile.txt; done
```

Comment: I added "-maxdepth 1" to the second "find" - now it does exactly what I want it to.

Thank you.

Comment: ... Sorry, i'm new to this site. \*Accept\*
(And i'm commenting this, even though i know this textbox told me not to)