# Show files in current directory using Git Bash?

Tags: git, directory, git-bash, working-directory

How can I check files in current directory, from git bash?
Like command `dir`, in Windows `cmd` ?

I found a command `git ls-files`, but it's work only with git repository files. But if I navegate through drive C:\, and want to see files in current directory, how can I do that in git bash?

Comment: Wow, thanks! I googled for that long time and nowhere found that simple command.) Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The git bash is basically a Unix shell, therefore you can list current files and directories with the `ls` command

You can also use `ls -a` to show hidden files and folders.

Since it is a Unix shell, you can make an alias called `dir` in a .bashrc file. It's handy when you are on windows, such that you don't have to remember both the Linux and the Windows command for listing directories.

Answer (score 5):

The command you are looking for is called `ls` (for list). Run it as

```
ls -als
```

to see all files and directories in the current directory.

Take a look at the Bash tutorial here, which will give you an overview of the most commonly used commands.

http://www.cs.uwp.edu/staff/knautz/BashTutorial-1.0.0/bt.php?p=tutorial01

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`ls`](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) should be enough.

since git bash is a regular [unix bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), regular unix commands do work.

---

That being said, I prefer using a regular cmd session, using the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) script provided with msysgit.
That way, all git commands are available while the regular DOS commands do work.

Answer (score 1):

Git bash runs bash, so you can use bash commands, i.e:

```
ls -la
```

You can have a look at basic bash commands, to list files, delete, show content, etc, here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/basic.html