# git bash "Not a git repository" error

Tags: git, github, version-control

I cloned one of my projects in windows desktop and after editing when I input `git add .` command then I get following error:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How to solve this?

Comment: How you cloned the project? Are you sure that you have copied `.git` directory (which usually is hidden) too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `git clone` it will create a subdirectory in the current directory. e.g. If your current working directory is `/code`, the command line output could look similar to this:

```
$ pwd
/home/you/code [or something similar]
$ ls -F
foo  bar
$ git clone http://somewhere.baz/somerepo.git
[happy git output]
$ ls -F
foo  bar  somerepo/
```

as you see you repo was cloned to the `somerepo` subdirectory, so the full path would be something like `~/code/repo_name`. However, your current working directory remains the same, `~/code`.

Next, you should step into that directory:

```
$ cd somerepo
$ ls
[content of your repo]
```

After you've changed the current working directory, you should be able to see its content (output of `ls` command), and be able to see git repository state with the `git status` command.

- [Cloning git repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)
- [Current working directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188182/how-to-get-current-working-directory)
- [Current direcroty content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738331/git-bash-show-files-in-current-directory)
- [CD tool man page](http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html)

Comment: I think cloning the repository is not always helpful.  Especially if local changes have been made.