# How to Check if Unknown File Exist Using Bash Script

Tags: bash

In a directory, "Global" I have muliple files and directories.  The file names are not consitant.  They might or might not have extension, there's upper and lower case letters along with numbers in the filename.

```
abc.txt
aBCd
abcd124fg
123ABCD.csv
```

I would like to check, If there are any files in the "Global" directory then just list all the file names but not the  directories.  Is this possible since I don't know what the file name will be?

Comment: `for i in Global/*; do [ -f "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done` or, `find Global -maxdepth 1 -type f` To ignore empty files in the first example, change `-f` to `-s`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list only files and not directories of a directory Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574794/how-to-list-only-files-and-not-directories-of-a-directory-bash)

Comment: The command to works great on how to list only the files but If I want to check if the file exist, how do I go about doing this.  So something like this:

`if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   for i in Global/*; do [ -f "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
else
   echo "No Files to see here"
fi`

But since I don't know what the filename is call or even if it has an extension.  How do I do check if there's any files in the Global directory?

`if [ -f $FILE ]; then`

So what would $FILE be??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the find command in bash and let it gather all that's in Global:

```
find ./Global -type f -name '*' -printf '%f\n'
```

That will give you all the existing files/names inside Global and subdirectories without anything else. The "%f" will give you the filenames only without the path.

This is basically all you need to loop through or if-state whatever you want with this list - it can be saved in an array or in a textfile you can then use for anything you want, like your task, which would be:

```
if [[ $(find ./Global -type f -name '*' -printf '%f\n') ]]; then
    echo "Files found in Global"
else
    echo "No files in Global"
fi
```