# Bash script to remove all image files from a given directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the following shell-script to clean the after-effects of a python script that I am running:

```
echo "Cleaning up..."
# some other files removed here...
# removing some log files
if [ -f log_errors.txt ]; then
    rm log_errors.txt
fi
# removing all the generated image files
if [ -f IMG_* ]; then
    rm IMG_*
fi
# some more files removed here...
ls
```

But, on doing `bash clean.sh`, I am getting the following error:

```
Cleaning up...
clean.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Consider that there are no sub-folders within this directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IMG_*` is being expanded to the full list of files matching the pattern, so your test will end up being something like `if [ -f IMG_1 IMG_2 IMG_3 ...`, which is too many arguments!

If you always want to remove all the files matching the pattern, then just pass the `-f` argument to `rm` and lose the `if`:

```
rm -f IMG_*
```

This will remove everything it can and do nothing if no files were found.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I added this **if** condition to take care of the case if a given file does not exist. So, if I want to remove multiple files matching a pattern, I can directly use **rm** without giving this **if** condition, but if I want to remove a specific file, you mean, I need to check its existence then?

Comment: In addition to Tom's answer, in case you HAVE to iterate over the files and do individual comparisons (possibly on something other than the name) then take a look at :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265272/how-to-list-files-in-directory-using-bash

Comment: @Adarsh if you want to remove a specific file but you're not sure if it exists, then you can use `rm -f specific_file`. It's up to you if you want to check whether it exists separately; you don't have to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in IMG_* ; do
    if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

This will iterate over all of files starting with `IMG_` and run `rm` on them.

And this omit subfolders if they exist..

EDIT:
Fixed due to comments

Comment: Quote `$f`, and either use `shopt -s nullglob` or add `[ -f "$f" ] || break` to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Failing to double-quote $f can be dangerous. If A is a file, B is a file and "A B" is a file, `f="A B"; rm $f;` will delete A and B, but not "A B".

Comment: True. Changed according to your comments.

Comment: The loop appears to offer no advantages over `rm -f IMG_*` while introducing a number of pesky pitfalls.

Comment: Also, if `$f` could have disappeared between expanding the wildcard and checking for its existence, what's to say it can't disappear between checking for its existence and actually attempting to remove it?

Comment: @tripleee `[ -f "$f" ]` checks whether it's a file or directory so it's not trying to `rm` directory. I'm not saying it's perfect but if you want to do something else except simply removing all files - this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my not precise answer before.

Follow code On centos 6.5 works.
If run on current directory. with `-maxdepth 1`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "IMG_*" -or -name "log_errors.txt" -exec rm -fv {} +
```

and you'd batter run

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "IMG_*" -or -name "log_errors.txt"`

make sure before with `-exec`

or

```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name "IMG_*" -or -name "log_errors.txt" | xargs  -I {} -t rm -fv {}
```

Thanks mklement0. you are nice man. (:

Comment: Promising, but you need `-o` (or `-or`) between the `-name` tests, you should use `-exec rm -fv {} +` to only invoke `rm` _once_, you should use an explicit target dir. - `find . -name ...` - for POSIX compliance (only _GNU_ `find` allows omitting it). Finally, even though the OP says there are no subdirs., I recommend adding `-maxdepth 1` so as to better mirror the OP's own solution attempt; `-type f` can't hurt, either.

Comment: Get it .  I think too little . Thank you for your advice. ( :

Comment: You're welcome, but please note that I was offering advice so you could _amend your answer_. If you don't want to implement _all_ of my suggestions, please at least do the _minimum_ to make your answer _work_, because it currently _does not work at all_: to make it work (inefficiently) with GNU `find`, place operator `-or` between the two `-name` tests.

Comment: I have changed my answer. Next time I will run the command before i commit it. regards

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer; +1.  The most efficient solution is `-exec rm -fv {} +`, as it will (typically) only invoke `rm` _once_, with (typically) _all_ filenames. Re `xargs`: the `-n1` option makes no sense here, as it will be overruled by `-i` (one invocation per input line, with the input line passed as a _single_ argument); also, `-i` is deprecated in favor of `-I {}`, and if you use the latter, the command will also be POSIX-compliant.

Comment: fixed .  I often works on  one linux system(centos). So don't too much care about POSIX-compliant. Today very productive in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check the existence of the files, you can use:

```
imgs=(IMG_*)
[ -f "${imgs[0]}" ] && rm "${imgs[@]}"
```

It works whether `nullglob` option is set or not, as `${imgs[0]}` will be the pattern `IMG_*` if there is no such file.

If you set the option using `shopt -s nullglob`, you can check with (note the use of a subshell - `(...)` - to localize the effect of setting `nullglob`):

```
(shopt -s nullglob; imgs=(IMG_*)
[ ${#imgs[@]} -gt 0 ] && rm "${imgs[@]}")
```

Comment: No, don't use `ls` in scripts. And the `-n` test will fail or do the wrong thing with different globbing options.

Comment: @tripleee Can you give me some hints about the globbing options?

Comment: Neither `[ ... ]` nor `[[ ... ]]` support globbing with operators such as `-n` or `-f`: `[ ... ]` _will_ expand `IMG_*` - and therefore typically break, because `-n` only accepts _1_ operand - whereas `[[ ... ]]` will _not_ expand `IMG_*` and therefore _always_ report true.

Comment: I'm mainly thinking of `nullglob` which your answer presupposes, but which is not usually enabled by default.

Comment: You could use a subshell as follows, but a subshell is expensive (may not be an issue), and it's not exactly pretty: `[[ -n $(shopt -s nullglob; echo IMG_*) ]]`.

Comment: @Yous: If you use `[ ... ]` rather than `[[ ... ]]`, you must double-quote `${imgs[0]}`. Also, since you've already collected all matches in an array, use `rm "${imgs[@]}"`. You don't need a _function_ to localize the effect of setting `nullglob` - a simple _subshell_ will do: `(shopt -s nullglbo; imgs=...)`. Finally, I suggest simply _removing_ the original, incorrect answer (you can leave an abstract comment behind that you've substantially reworked the answer).

Comment: @mklement0 Wait... I think I need to put the rest code into the subshell, don't I?

Comment: Yes, you do. I took the liberty of doing it for you.The `imgs` variable won't be visible outside the subshell, so you need to include _all_ related commands in the subshell.