# Shell script print out file names when given a folder

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am writing a shell script.. given a a folder as a command line arg it will print out the names of the files/folders in it

```
#!/bin/sh
folder="$1"
for f in "$folder"
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

This only prints out some the first file/folder of the given folder.

Comment: Ignacio has provided a good solution here [how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Darrenrogers: Actually it doesn't. Your program just output the first parameter which is passed to your script, whatever it is. Note also that you have - perhaps incorrectly - tagged your question with *bash*. Unless you explicitly invoke this script by `bash SCRIPTNAME ...`, it won't be executed by bash, but by sh. I suggest that you remove the *bash* tag.

Answer (score 5):

You need shell globbing operator `*` after `$folder` separated by the directory separator `/`:

```
for f in "$folder"/*
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

`*` would expand to all files inside `$folder`.

As an aside, i see you have used `sh` (not `bash`) as the script interpreter; `sh` is not `bash` in all systems (e.g. in Ubuntu), so if you were to use `bash` (does not make any difference in this case though), explicitly use `bash` in the Shebang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

Comment: as nullglob option is off by default, a check `[[ -e $f ]]` may be added in case glob expands to `$folder'/*'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `find` command:

```
folder="$1"
find "$folder"
```

As @Anubis pointed out in comments, the `find` command is recursive by default: it will also search for files/folders into subdirectories starting from target folder. You can restrict results to the current directory with the `-mindepth` and `-mindepth` options:

```
find "$folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

Note that the target directory will be listed too if you omit `-mindepth 1`

Comment: yes but this will start from the target directory and recurse into all the subdirectories. Better to mention that this can be controlled with `mindepth` and `maxdepth`. e.g. `find "$folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` will list only the first level content etc..

Comment: It must be noted that here, if `-mindepth 1` is omitted, target directory also will be listed, which is not produced in the answer given by heemayl